# blender 2.69: Texture is not shown correctly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting

I have created two objects: plane and polygon. Then i joined them together to new mesh. For that new mesh i created a texture. Texture is shown in texture view, but not in cycles render completly. Only one object displays the texture but not the rest.

Picture is here:   [image]

Is that a bug? Perhaps i made something wrong.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend? It's hard to tell what might be going on from your screenshot.

Comment: Hi gandalf3, i cannot find a button to upload my blender file. I wanted to do exactly that. Where is the button? Drag and Drop is not working as well.

Comment: There isn't one on the site, but you can use [pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if both objects **already have a material** before being joined. Blender will copy all materials assigned in the source object to the destination object, all faces still assigned to the same material prior to joining. When you're creating a new texture, it's *only assigned to one material*, so it doesn't show up on faces still assigned to other materials when rendered.

The object's UV image could still be shown as you intended in the viewport, because it's assigned through [`image`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.MeshTextureFace.html#bpy.types.MeshTextureFace.image) attribute of the object's UV map. It doesn't rely on [`Texture`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Texture.html) data at all. But what's rendered, do rely on it.

If this is the case, *remove* the unwanted material's slot, *assign faces* from the other object to the intended material, or *assign the same texture* to all materials in the object.

Comment: This was the solution, thank you very much. I realized now that my new object consists of two materials after joining. I deleted one material and now all is shown again.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to check these points:

Remove doubles.
Recalculate normals.
UV Unwrap mesh (both meshes).

I had some problems with scale, so try to apply scale (Ctrl + A)

Comment: I have done exactly this: remove doubles (no doubles were found), Recalculate normals, unwraped the finished endmodel. In 3Dview/textureView it is correctly displayed. But the render doesn't show it correct.